# Place svg image created by d3.js before a HTML node

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

[image]

I have a base map that is shown in the above image and I want to show data related to each node using the pie/ bar chart alongside each node. I am using d3.js to create the chart but not able to place the chart alongside of each node (as shown in image below)

[image]

I have tried to used append and insert method provided by D3.js library but it does not seem to be working. Any leads to achieving the result would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

</head>
    <body>
            <!-- Load d3.js -->
            <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

            <svg id="svg" width="1851" height="1806" viewBox="0 0 1851 1806" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect width="1851" height="1806" fill="#E5E5E5"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 8" cx="558" cy="341" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 17" cx="1038" cy="234" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 9" cx="300" cy="639" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 10" cx="1498" cy="970" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 11" cx="1400" cy="1401" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 12" cx="399" cy="1322" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 16" cx="1279" cy="1562" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 15" cx="928" cy="1562" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 14" cx="546" cy="1562" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 13" cx="229" cy="1562" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <g id="Group 3">
                <circle id="Ellipse 1" cx="783" cy="932" r="224.5" stroke="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 1" d="M898.314 738.715L880.994 738.638L889.721 723.677L898.314 738.715Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 6" d="M567.968 932.078L550.788 929.871L561.29 916.097L567.968 932.078Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 5" d="M663.973 1124.68L681.293 1124.62L672.68 1139.65L663.973 1124.68Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 3" d="M891.549 1129.26L902.904 1116.18L908.553 1132.56L891.549 1129.26Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 2" d="M1008 932.3L999.803 917.039L1017.11 917.574L1008 932.3Z" fill="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 9">
                <line id="Line 1" x1="269" y1="1561.5" x2="506" y2="1561.5" stroke="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 7" d="M269.219 1562L284.404 1553.67L284.026 1570.98L269.219 1562Z" fill="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 8">
                <line id="Line 2" x1="586" y1="1561.5" x2="888" y2="1561.5" stroke="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 8" d="M890.071 1562.14L875.009 1570.7L875.133 1553.38L890.071 1562.14Z" fill="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 12">
                <line id="Line 6" x1="228.5" y1="1522" x2="228.5" y2="1322" stroke="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 13" d="M229.274 1312.14L237.727 1327.26L220.408 1327.02L229.274 1312.14Z" fill="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 10">
                <line id="Line 5" x1="426.435" y1="1348.75" x2="524.435" y2="1521.75" stroke="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 10" d="M528.164 1526.36L513.514 1517.12L528.842 1509.05L528.164 1526.36Z" fill="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 11">
                <line id="Line 4" x1="372.404" y1="1349.29" x2="246.404" y2="1522.29" stroke="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 12" d="M238.986 1525.13L243.668 1508.45L255.769 1520.84L238.986 1525.13Z" fill="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 13">
                <line id="Line 7" x1="377.561" y1="1282.24" x2="314.561" y2="1167.24" stroke="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 11" d="M382.164 1290.36L367.514 1281.12L382.842 1273.05L382.164 1290.36Z" fill="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 7">
                <line id="Line 3" x1="968" y1="1561.5" x2="1239" y2="1561.5" stroke="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 9" d="M1239.07 1562.14L1224.01 1570.7L1224.13 1553.38L1239.07 1562.14Z" fill="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 2">
                <path id="Polygon 15" d="M567.361 793.935L550.068 794.913L557.867 779.448L567.361 793.935Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 14" d="M333.367 661.711L350.447 664.583L339.42 677.94L333.367 661.711Z" fill="black"/>
                <line id="Line 8" x1="331.487" y1="663.127" x2="564.487" y2="793.127" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 1">
                <path id="Polygon 16" d="M691.209 728.119L678.696 740.095L674.581 723.271L691.209 728.119Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Vector 1" d="M568 380C568 578 474 686 676 730" stroke="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 5">
                <path id="Polygon 17" d="M1519.03 1020.27L1503.12 1027.12L1505.15 1009.92L1519.03 1020.27Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 18" d="M1419.71 1376.63L1427.08 1360.95L1436.97 1375.17L1419.71 1376.63Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Vector 2" d="M1506.62 1012.07C1606.95 1178.02 1474.41 1340.84 1425 1370.04" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 15">
                <path id="Polygon 19" d="M1118.99 479.678L1123.32 496.449L1106.63 491.811L1118.99 479.678Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Vector 3" d="M823 697C1063.46 697 1116 489 1116 489" stroke="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 17">
                <path id="Polygon 20" d="M1058.41 268.41L1073.81 276.34L1059.24 285.711L1058.41 268.41Z" fill="black"/>
                <line id="Line 9" x1="1060.86" y1="273.484" x2="1116.86" y2="366.484" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 14">
                <path id="Polygon 21" d="M614.597 1401.48L609.124 1417.91L597.629 1404.96L614.597 1401.48Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Vector 4" d="M478 1437C545.2 1472.2 586 1423 606 1411" stroke="black"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 6">
                <path id="Polygon 24" d="M1259.89 1530.5L1243.37 1525.3L1256.13 1513.59L1259.89 1530.5Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 23" d="M1146.41 1412.72L1162.9 1418.01L1150.07 1429.65L1146.41 1412.72Z" fill="black"/>
                <line id="Line 10" x1="1152.71" y1="1421.3" x2="1260.71" y2="1530.3" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 16">
                <path id="Polygon 22" d="M1039.07 1411.14L1024.01 1419.7L1024.13 1402.38L1039.07 1411.14Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Vector 5" d="M930 1523C930 1523 938 1407 1030 1413" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Group 4">
                <path id="Polygon 26" d="M1004.51 818.604L1020.92 824.148L1007.91 835.587L1004.51 818.604Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Polygon 25" d="M1463.11 959.919L1449.33 970.414L1447.13 953.233L1463.11 959.919Z" fill="black"/>
                <path id="Vector 6" d="M1009.5 824.5C1122.5 917.5 1309.5 984.5 1459.5 961" stroke="black"/>
                </g>
                <circle id="Ellipse 18" cx="783" cy="703" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 23" cx="600" cy="812" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 22" cx="597" cy="1033" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 21" cx="783" cy="1157" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 20" cx="981" cy="1033" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                <circle id="Ellipse 19" cx="963" cy="816" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
                </svg>

                
        <script>
            var width = 30,
             height = 30,
                radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
                
            var data = [{"letter":"q","presses":1},{"letter":"w","presses":5},{"letter":"e","presses":2}];
            console.log(data);

            var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#2C93E8","#838690","#F56C4E"]);

            var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) { return d.presses; })(data);
            var arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(0);
            var labelArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 40).innerRadius(radius - 40);

            var svg = d3.select("#Ellipse 8")
                    .insert("svg", "Ellipse 8")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 +")"); // Moving the center point. 1/2 the width and 1/2 the height

            var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
                        .data(pie)
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .attr("class", "arc");
            
                g.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.letter);});

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I see an error and will try to fix it and give you a working answer.

Comment: Check out my answer, I did an example to add one of the pie charts to the circles, but you could do the same for each circle easily following the same pattern. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. I highly appreciate your effort.

Comment: Great, no worries. If I solved your problem please consider to vote as accepted answer and up-vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty cool, I guess its a Krebs Cycle?

Gives me an idea for something similar (in terms of how it looks) - 6 port 2 position selector valve for HPLC :)

Anyway, in general you can try something like this:

```
var parentEl = d3.select("div").node();
parentEl.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), parentEl.childNodes[0]);
```

As a simple example:

```js
var g = d3.select('#myG').node();
var circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
circle.setAttribute('r', 10);
circle.setAttribute('fill', '#ff0000');
//here we insert the circle before the first element, i.e. the text element
g.insertBefore(circle, g.childNodes[0]);
//if we switch the above line for this then the circle is appended at the end - after the text element
//g.appendChild(circle);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=500 height=500>
  <g id="myG" transform="translate(50, 50)">
    <text id="someID">Text example</text>
  </g>  
</svg>
```

svg is a bit different to pure HTML because we also have position and translation of each element, and additionally, svg elements are "painted" in the order in which they appear in the DOM, so here we can tell that the circle is before the text element because it is painted first, and so the text element is painted after it and on top of it.

If we switch `g.insertBefore(circle, g.childNodes[0]);` for `g.appendChild(circle);` then the circle is painted over the text element

My example is a bit basic because I don't have your code to show you a more applied and real answer.

If you share a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), in a standalone code snippet here or in codePen etc. then I can give a more applied and real answer.

**UPDATE after OP added code**

```js
var width = 30,
    height = 30,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var data = [{"letter":"q","presses":1},{"letter":"w","presses":5},{"letter":"e","presses":2}];
console.log(data);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#2C93E8","#838690","#F56C4E"]);

var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) { return d.presses; })(data);
var arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(0);
var labelArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 40).innerRadius(radius - 40);

var circ = document.querySelector("#Group_18 > circle");            
var svg = document.querySelector("#svg");
const box = circ.getBoundingClientRect();
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
pt.x = (box.left + box.right)/2;
pt.y = box.top
var svgP = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());            

var circ_g = d3.select("#Group_18")
  // .insert("g", "#g")
  // .attr("width", width)
  // .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${svgP.x}, ${svgP.y - 40}) scale(7)`);
  // Moving the center point of the group to add the pie chart to to just above the #Group_18 circle

var g = circ_g.selectAll("arc")
  .data(pie)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.letter);});
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Load d3.js -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

  <svg id="svg" width="555.3" height="541.8" viewBox="0 0 1851 1806" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="1851" height="1806" fill="#E5E5E5"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_8" cx="558" cy="341" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_17" cx="1038" cy="234" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_9" cx="300" cy="639" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_10" cx="1498" cy="970" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_11" cx="1400" cy="1401" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_12" cx="399" cy="1322" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_16" cx="1279" cy="1562" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_15" cx="928" cy="1562" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_14" cx="546" cy="1562" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_13" cx="229" cy="1562" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    <g id="Group_3">
      <circle id="Ellipse_1" cx="783" cy="932" r="224.5" stroke="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_1" d="M898.314 738.715L880.994 738.638L889.721 723.677L898.314 738.715Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_6" d="M567.968 932.078L550.788 929.871L561.29 916.097L567.968 932.078Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_5" d="M663.973 1124.68L681.293 1124.62L672.68 1139.65L663.973 1124.68Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_3" d="M891.549 1129.26L902.904 1116.18L908.553 1132.56L891.549 1129.26Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_2" d="M1008 932.3L999.803 917.039L1017.11 917.574L1008 932.3Z" fill="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_9">
      <line id="Line_1" x1="269" y1="1561.5" x2="506" y2="1561.5" stroke="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_7" d="M269.219 1562L284.404 1553.67L284.026 1570.98L269.219 1562Z" fill="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_8">
      <line id="Line_2" x1="586" y1="1561.5" x2="888" y2="1561.5" stroke="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_8" d="M890.071 1562.14L875.009 1570.7L875.133 1553.38L890.071 1562.14Z" fill="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_12">
      <line id="Line_6" x1="228.5" y1="1522" x2="228.5" y2="1322" stroke="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_13" d="M229.274 1312.14L237.727 1327.26L220.408 1327.02L229.274 1312.14Z" fill="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_10">
      <line id="Line_5" x1="426.435" y1="1348.75" x2="524.435" y2="1521.75" stroke="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_10" d="M528.164 1526.36L513.514 1517.12L528.842 1509.05L528.164 1526.36Z" fill="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_11">
      <line id="Line_4" x1="372.404" y1="1349.29" x2="246.404" y2="1522.29" stroke="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_12" d="M238.986 1525.13L243.668 1508.45L255.769 1520.84L238.986 1525.13Z" fill="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_13">
      <line id="Line_7" x1="377.561" y1="1282.24" x2="314.561" y2="1167.24" stroke="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_11" d="M382.164 1290.36L367.514 1281.12L382.842 1273.05L382.164 1290.36Z" fill="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group 7">
      <line id="Line_3" x1="968" y1="1561.5" x2="1239" y2="1561.5" stroke="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_9" d="M1239.07 1562.14L1224.01 1570.7L1224.13 1553.38L1239.07 1562.14Z" fill="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_2">
      <path id="Polygon_15" d="M567.361 793.935L550.068 794.913L557.867 779.448L567.361 793.935Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_14" d="M333.367 661.711L350.447 664.583L339.42 677.94L333.367 661.711Z" fill="black"/>
      <line id="Line_8" x1="331.487" y1="663.127" x2="564.487" y2="793.127" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_1">
      <path id="Polygon_16" d="M691.209 728.119L678.696 740.095L674.581 723.271L691.209 728.119Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Vector_1" d="M568 380C568 578 474 686 676 730" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_5">
      <path id="Polygon_17" d="M1519.03 1020.27L1503.12 1027.12L1505.15 1009.92L1519.03 1020.27Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_18" d="M1419.71 1376.63L1427.08 1360.95L1436.97 1375.17L1419.71 1376.63Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Vector_2" d="M1506.62 1012.07C1606.95 1178.02 1474.41 1340.84 1425 1370.04" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_15">
      <path id="Polygon_19" d="M1118.99 479.678L1123.32 496.449L1106.63 491.811L1118.99 479.678Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Vector_3" d="M823 697C1063.46 697 1116 489 1116 489" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_17">
      <path id="Polygon_20" d="M1058.41 268.41L1073.81 276.34L1059.24 285.711L1058.41 268.41Z" fill="black"/>
      <line id="Line_9" x1="1060.86" y1="273.484" x2="1116.86" y2="366.484" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_14">
      <path id="Polygon_21" d="M614.597 1401.48L609.124 1417.91L597.629 1404.96L614.597 1401.48Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Vector_4" d="M478 1437C545.2 1472.2 586 1423 606 1411" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_6">
      <path id="Polygon_24" d="M1259.89 1530.5L1243.37 1525.3L1256.13 1513.59L1259.89 1530.5Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_23" d="M1146.41 1412.72L1162.9 1418.01L1150.07 1429.65L1146.41 1412.72Z" fill="black"/>
      <line id="Line_10" x1="1152.71" y1="1421.3" x2="1260.71" y2="1530.3" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_16">
      <path id="Polygon_22" d="M1039.07 1411.14L1024.01 1419.7L1024.13 1402.38L1039.07 1411.14Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Vector_5" d="M930 1523C930 1523 938 1407 1030 1413" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_4">
      <path id="Polygon_26" d="M1004.51 818.604L1020.92 824.148L1007.91 835.587L1004.51 818.604Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Polygon_25" d="M1463.11 959.919L1449.33 970.414L1447.13 953.233L1463.11 959.919Z" fill="black"/>
      <path id="Vector_6" d="M1009.5 824.5C1122.5 917.5 1309.5 984.5 1459.5 961" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_18" class="Ellipse_g">
      <circle id="Ellipse_18" cx="783" cy="703" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_23" class="Ellipse_g">
      <circle id="Ellipse_23" cx="600" cy="812" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_22" class="Ellipse_g">  
      <circle id="Ellipse_22" cx="597" cy="1033" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_21" class="Ellipse_g">  
      <circle id="Ellipse_21" cx="783" cy="1157" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_20" class="Ellipse_g">  
      <circle id="Ellipse_20" cx="981" cy="1033" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Group_19" class="Ellipse_g">  
      <circle id="Ellipse_19" cx="963" cy="816" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Few comments, you can't have ids that have spaces, as then the `document.querySelector()` that d3.js uses under the hood fails. (Example: `d3.select('#Group 10')` It would look for an element with tagName 10 that is descendent of an element with the id of "Group" - essentially looking for: `<g id="Group"><10></10></g>` which is not what we want)

So I changed from e.g. `<g id="Group 10" .../>` to `<g id="Group_10" .../>` etc.

Also, I wrapped the circles in groups to make it easier to then append into those groups:

```
<g id="Group_18" class="Ellipse_g">
    <circle id="Ellipse_18" cx="783" cy="703" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
</g>
<g id="Group_23" class="Ellipse_g">
    <circle id="Ellipse_23" cx="600" cy="812" r="39.5" fill="white" stroke="black"/>
</g>
... etc.
```

Then I appended your pie chart into this group like so:

```
var circ = document.querySelector("#Group_18 > circle");            
var svg = document.querySelector("#svg");
const box = circ.getBoundingClientRect();
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
pt.x = (box.left + box.right)/2;
pt.y = box.top
var svgP = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());            

var circ_g = d3.select("#Group_18")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${svgP.x}, ${svgP.y - 40}) scale(7)`);
  // Moving the center point of the group to add the pie chart to to just above the #Group_18 circle

var g = circ_g.selectAll("arc")
  .data(pie)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.letter);});
```

Result is:

[image]

Full demo also here: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/ExjmabY

Comment: what do I do to append another pie chart to the left of that pie chart we have appended earlier? @Alex L

Comment: Hey Prem, see my updated codePen for a simplified example: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/ExjmabY - If you want to do this more than twice it starts to become a lot of repeated code and you might like to do it with some functions, but at least my simple example should illustrate the idea - greate two group elements, each for a chart, and translate them plus and minus 35 units from the center of the circle below to center them left and right.

Comment: when i am changing the svg image then I am getting some error like *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSVGPoint' of null* https://codepen.io/prem0862/pen/QWbqMpK?editors=1010 can you please take a look on it? TIA

Comment: I was using a query selector of ``id = svg`` i.e. '#svg'. You have removed the id of "svg". You can either add it back to the svg tag like ``<svg id='svg' />`` or you can change line 27 to ``var svg = document.querySelector("svg");``